# How to create database taking Students meal attendance taking

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create student meal attendance system for like school/university/college.
And the system will include this:-

Students can eat 3 time a day (breakfast, lunch and dinner) but they can't eat breakfast or any other meal more than once.

I was trying to create it like this but I don't know how to restrict them can anyone help.

**Students**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Stud12 | Abebe |

**Meal**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Breakfast |
| 2 | Lunch |
| 3 | Dinner |

**Meal Attendance**

| Id | Stud_id | Meal_id | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stud12 | 1 | 03-04-2021 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You can check before insert to `MealAttendance`

Example:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MealAttendance WHERE Meal_id = 1 and Stud_id = 1 and Date = '03-04-2021')
```

If the row exists, you can restrict.